# How to get Authentication Service user account info in front-end?

Tags: sapui5, saml-2.0, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-identity-services

I am building a HTML5 application in SCP, using Portal Service to manage roles. Back-end developer asked me to give them role info (ID or e-mail) as an input of an interface (They need this authentication info). How to get it?

Is there any front-end API provided to get these info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User API** provides few details about user in **HCP**.
To use the user API in your HTML5 application, add a route to your `neo-app.jso`n application descriptor file as follows:

```
"routes": [
   {
     "path": "/services/userapi", //application path to be forwarded
     "target": {
       "type": "service",
       "name": "userapi"
     }
  }
]
```

A sample URL for the route defined above would look like this: `/services/userapi/currentUser`.

An example response could return the following user data:

```
{
  "name": "p12345678",
  "firstName": "Jon",
  "lastName": "Snow",
  "email": "jon.snow@tina.com",
  "displayName": "Jon Snow (p12345678)"
}
```

[More info here](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?1de599bf722446849d2b2e10132df42a.html)

Comment: Hi, Sunil, can I get this info in FLP of cloud foundry? Should I add this route in `xs-app.json` since there is no neo-app.json in cloud foundry ?

Comment: Hi Tina, I am not sure. I don't have knowledge of cloud foundry.